# C# - Using overriden getter

Tags: c#, getter

I have a project called `Common` along with several other projects. Inside the `Common` project, I have a class named `ItemBase`. Inside that class, I have a virtual getter called `CachedReference`, it looks like so:

```
public virtual ItemData CachedReference
{
    get
    {
        return new ItemData();
    }
}
```

Now, I'm returning an empty `ItemData` object because I want the classes that inherit from `ItemBase` to override this getter so it will refer to the **overriden getter** and not the default one (I would make it an abstract class, but I can't because the `Common` project initializes instances of this class).

In my other projects I have a class named `Item` which inherits from the `ItemBase` class and overrides the getter. It looks like so:

```
public override ItemData CachedReference
    {
        get
        {
            return LoginServer.Instance.ItemDataProvider[this.MapleId];
        }
    }
```

The constructor of the `ItemBase`class uses the `CachedReference` property to set it's data. However, when I initialize a new instance of the `Item`class that uses the default constructor of `ItemBase`, it refers to the **default** getter rather than the **overriden** one.

Why's that happening? I want to refer the overriden getter only, not the default one so each project can return it's own `CachedReference`.

**EDIT:** I've been asked to show how I use `CachedReference`, so here:

```
public ItemBase(int mapleId, short quantity = 1)
{
    this.MapleId = mapleId;
    this.Quantity = quantity;

    this.WeaponAttack = this.CachedReference.WeaponAttack;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You will need to be more explicit  (i.e. provide code) about how you are instantiating the class and calling the property.

Comment: Also, I suggest replacing `return new ItemData();` with `throw new NotSupportedException()`.

Comment: I don't think the base class *can* invoke the overridden member, that's not really how `virtual` members work.  The base class invokes its own, the child class invokes its own (or explicitly invokes the base class').  The behavior you're looking for is `abstract`, not `virtual`.

Comment: @AntP I'm calling CachedReference from the constructor of the ItemBase class to set some properties, I would provide the code if it matter to the question.

Comment: @David I would want to use abstract but unfortunately I'm instantiating the ItemBase class from the Common project, so it's not possible in this case.

Comment: Please [create an example that reproduces the problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNHwLn). See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This code works as you expect. Can you provide a compilable code of your's that demonstrates your problem?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var derived = new Derived();
}

public class Base
{
    protected string _p = "Base";
    public virtual string P
    {           
        get { Console.WriteLine("Base get"); return _p; }
        set { Console.WriteLine("Base set"); _p = value; }
    }

    public Base()
    {
        P = "Base constructor";
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override string P
    {           
        get { Console.WriteLine("Derived get"); return _p; }
        set { Console.WriteLine("Derived set"); _p = value; }
    }

    public Derived()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(P);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Derived set
Derived get
Base constructor
```